# TemplateDoesNotExist base.html

Tags: python, django

Getting issue while calling base.html in to other html pages
Getting issue as,

`Exception Type:    TemplateDoesNotExist
 Exception Value:   base.html`

Below is my settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<h1>Django</h1>
{% block content %}
<h1>Django</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]
Any suggestions

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and post the (relevant) file tree?

Comment: File tree is posted. Please verify

Comment: probably it should be `{% extends "LoginReg/base.html" %}`.

Comment: template dir are incorrect

Answer (score 8):

You're very close! Django is looking in the `templates/` directory for `base.html`, but Django isn't able to find it because you have an intermediate directory called `LoginReg/` which is holding `base.html`

Try replacing `{% extends "base.html" %}` with `{% extends "LoginReg/base.html" %}` in your `index.html` file instead, which is the proper path to the `base.html` template file.

Comment: @jim-macaulay Would you kindly accept this answer as the correct one based on the community upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error. after I searched in stackoverflow, but i can't find the answer. I copy the base.html file to templates/base.html and in all file call extends base.html. I writes {% extends '../base.html' %}.it run good for me.  I hope everyone have same error can fix it (sorry about my english)